# matInput directive not working in lazy loaded module

Tags: angular

I have created a module for lazy loading which does work essentially, the problem is that for some reason things like `matInput` is not working. By that I mean that the `input` does not get its fancy look.

`MatInputModule` gets imported in the module accordingly:

```js
const routes = [
  {path: '', component: AddPlaceComponent}
];


const MaterialModules = [
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatInputModule,
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [    
    // Organisms
    PlaceAutocompleteComponent,    
    // Templates
    AddPlaceComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MaterialModules,
  ]
})
export class AddPlaceModule { }
```

The `PlaceAutocompleteComponent`, which is where the `input` is needed, is as simple as it gets:

```xml
<div>
  <input matInput placeholder="test" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

Still, the control looks like this:

[image]

I just don't see it. All other routes are working. The lazy loading works also fine and there are no warnings or errors in the console.

What am I missing?

I assume it has something to do with the lazy loading and/or routing?

Comment: try adding braces to `[matInput]="123"` and check console after it. angular should tell you something useful

Comment: @Andrei All I get is "*Can't bind to 'matInput' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.*". That error makes sense though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

matInputs should be used inside `<mat-form-field><input matInput></mat-form-field>`

Comment: That does not change anything. Actually, that's how I import all my modules.

Comment: I don't know how many times this has happened to me by now. I really should stop working 14h each day.